# Huge Ammonia in compost danger?

Tags: compost, safety

Is it safe to use a sealed container to compost the raw chicken manure? Because as far as I know, these nitrogen-rich materials generate huge ammonia when decomposing. If I use a sealed compost bin it can produce methane (due to lack of oxygen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composting is an aerobic process. In a sealed container you will get anaerobic decomposition, which usually produces a horrible-smelling slimy mess, not what is normally described as "compost".